# Lwuit disable virtual keyboard

Tags: user-interface, java-me

I am developing a j2me application using LWUIT as GUI .... how can I disable the navigation virtual keyboard appeared down in the touch screen ?

Comment: Removed LWUIT tag as that is a red herring, the solution below applies to any JavaME app on Symbian

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using a Symbian JavaME phone you can disable the virtual keypad by adding the

> Nokia-MIDlet-On-Screen-Keypad: no

Jad attribute to your JAD/Manifest..

Also take a look at this [blog entry](http://www.gorkem-ercan.com/2009/02/touch-enabling-java-me-applications.html) for more