# Disable joypad in s60 jme

Tags: java-me, symbian, s60, joystick

Can you tell me how to disable joypad in java-me?

I develop some app in sdk s40 6th fp1, and i what to portable app on some device with sdk s60.(Device Nokia 5230)

When app open, joypad is show on device with s60 sdk.

In app, i extends Canvas i show in Midlet.

Is possible disable joypad?

Answer (score 2):

I presume you mean the virtual keypad, since 5230 does not have a physical one. Take a look at the answer on  [Lwuit disable virtual keyboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4970048/lwuit-disable-virtual-keyboard/4983579#4983579) It also applies to your case